# Present two UIViewControllers on top of each other programmatically in one function

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am trying to present (1) a `ScrollViewController`, then after that is presented, present (2) an `ImagePicker`. However, only the `ScrollViewController` is presented, not the `ImagePicker` afterwards.

Individually, the below code works fine, just when one follows the other, it doesn't work. I've tried including one in the completion handler, still no luck.

There are no errors displayed, *except*, that when the sequence occurs, the Xcode debug area is shown but completely blank with no error messages or warnings.

**Questions:**

> What exactly is going on here that I'm missing? Why aren't both being presented? How can I ensure both the `ScrollViewController` and `ImagePicker` are displayed, one after the other?

**(1) ScrollViewController:**

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ScrollViewControllerID") as! ScrollViewController
 self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**(2) ImagePicker:**

```
 let imagePicker = MyImagePickerController()
 imagePicker.delegate = self
 imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
 imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
 imagePicker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
 self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You want one on top of the other, all at once, and then let the user dismiss the ImagePicker in order to show the ScrollViewController?

Comment: @BaseZen Yes, that would be a good final configuration that I would like to achieve. (But even just presenting one after the other I was wanting to know as well.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A View Controller can only present one presented controller at a time. Indeed, there is a property: `presentedViewController: UIViewController?` that implies this. To coordinate these actions:

A. Only present the *first* VC from your base VC.

B. In the completion handler of the first presentation call, let the *second* VC present the final one that goes on top:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ScrollViewControllerID") as! ScrollViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true) {
    let imagePicker = MyImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
    vc.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I have a follow on question if you are able to have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175823/closing-only-the-imagepicker-and-passing-image-to-scrollviewcontroller

Comment: Will it make `vc` being leaked?