# Closing only the ImagePicker and passing image to ScrollViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have an `ImagePicker` that is displayed after a `ScrollViewController` is presented (1).

**Question:**

> Once the image is picked from the `ImagePicker`, how do I dismiss
>   *just* the `ImagePicker` so that the `ScrollViewController` is displayed and then pass the image picked to the
>   `ScrollViewController`?

**(1) Presenting `ScrollViewController` and `ImagePicker`**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ScrollViewControllerID") as! ScrollViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true) {
    let imagePicker = MyImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
    vc.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Handling `ImagePicker` after it is closed**

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let myImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

//How to send myImage to the ScrollViewController and close ImagePicker?

}
```

Answer (score 0):

MyImagePickerController

```
class MyImagePickerController: ... {

     var controller:ScrollViewController!

     convenience init(controller: ScrollViewController) {
         self.init()
         self.controller = controller
     }

}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let myImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    controller.imageName = myImage
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

This is how you would apply it

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ScrollViewControllerID") as! ScrollViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true) {
    let imagePicker = MyImagePickerController(controller: vc)
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
    vc.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go at this. Can I get more understanding on what exactly this part does though? `convenience init(controller: ScrollViewController) { self.controller = controller}`

Comment: it provides your own custom initializer, a `convenience init` which allows you to take in your own variables. Then with those vrariables you can access stuff from other classes. So you take in the previous controller, as a variable, and you then can access the previous controller's items using `controller.items` or `controller.myImage`. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks @impression7vx But, which part of the code dismisses the `ImagePicker` but keeps the `ScrollViewController` on screen though?

Comment: Ahh I see! So to do that, you would just do `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` after `controller.imageName = myImage` and it should remove the imagepicker and present whatever was behind the imagePicker, i.e. your scrollView

Comment: Unfortunately the `convenience init` gives two errors: `Use of 'self' in property access 'controller' before self.init initializes self` and `Self.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer`. `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` also seems to dismiss both `ImagePicker` and `ScrollViewController` at the same time. However if I remove `imagePicker.delegate = self` only the `ImagePicker` is dismissed. I’ll have to look at this all more in depth to see what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it shortly.